# Replace string in CSS file (C#)

Tags: c#, css, .net, streamreader

I'm reading in a css file in this way:

```
string path_to_default_css = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/test.css");
string cssdefault = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I want to replace certain strings in this css files in this way:

```
cssdefault.Replace("#252830","#000000);
```

But replacement doesn't work.

This is the string representation of the readed in css file:

```
.slider-handle {
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: #252830;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #252830 0%, #252830 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #252830 0%, #252830 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #252830 0%, #252830 100%);
}
```

Comment: You could always include another CSS that overrides the stuff you want to change. You currently seem (can't tell, partial code, whats sr from?) to be trying to physically rewrite the file which will change it for everyone, is that what you want?

Comment: Are you inspecting the return value from `Replace`, or just the `cssdefault` string after the method call?  Strings are immutable in C#, hence you need the return value.

Comment: Are you doing `cssdefault = cssdefault.Replace("#252830", "#000000");`

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing all your code, I'm  not sure exactly what you are doing but a guess is that you are calling .Replace but not assigning the result to anything.

You need to do

```
cssdefault = cssdefault.Replace("#252830","#000000");
```